# How to use datamapper callbacks (or hooks) properly?

Tags: ruby, database, callback, sinatra, datamapper

I tried the following:

```
class DataEntry
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial,   :key => true
  property :some_data,    Text,   :length => 1000000
  property :created_at, DateTime

  after :save do |entry|
    if entry.created_at.strftime('%T') == "00:00:00"
      @new_datetime = ((entry.created_at.to_time+1)-3600).to_datetime
      entry.update!(:created_at => @new_datetime)
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

This should change the time an entry has been saved to 00:00:01 if it's 00:00:00 (hours:min:sec). I know my code is dirty (I'm learning ruby, datamapper, etc, I'm a bit of a noob ;) ), but what's even worse: it doesn't have any effect on the model. It just saves as if my hook wouldn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

(What's maybe also important: I'm using this with sinatra, so I can't access rails helpers like n.hours etc.!)

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you using `after`?

i would suggest to use `before` to avoid double operation on object.

by using `self` you can omit redundant `entry` using

and no need to `return true`

also, why instance variables?

```
before :save do
  if self.created_at.strftime('%T') == "00:00:00"
    self.created_at = ((self.created_at.to_time+1)-3600).to_datetime
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this, although the accepted answer provides a workaround, the answer to the original question about why the "after" hook wasn't firing is probably due to the fact that the "after :save" hook will not fire UNLESS the model is dirty when save is called!

So;

```
m = MyModel.first
m.save #Hook will not fire
m.name = "Foo"
m.save #Hook will fire
```

Little quirk of datamapper, you get a performance boost from doing things this way but the readability goes through the floor IMO.